# Can I improve my AdWords quality scores with better landing pages?

Tags: google-ads, ppc

I noticed that I have some keywords in my AdWords that are totally applicable to my site but the quality score of the keyword is 4 or 5. I'd like to get it up higher by creating custom versions of my site's home page (landing page) targeted specifically for people searching on those keywords.

So for example, if we pretend my site sells pet food, my current home page has the phrase "dog food." I have a specific AdWords campaign for people searching on cat food (with cat food-specific ads). I'm thinking about changing the URL on those ads to something like http://mysite.com/cat.html, so a different home page comes up with the phrase "cat food." My thinking is that will help Google see that this new landing page is appropriate for the keywords and will raise my quality score for the "cat food" keywords.

(Note that none of what I'm doing is shady or misleading; nobody would disagree that all of the keywords and ads I've created are perfect and appropriate for what my site offers.)

Question: is what I describe the correct way to raise poor quality scores on keywords, and will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct way to go about it. You can even use [keyword insertion](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2454041) to increase your click-through rate, which is another major consideration for quality score.

Maintaining separate Ad Groups for keywords with less than stellar quality scores will help prevent dragging down your other, better performing keywords.

When appropriate, you can also include keywords in the page title, heading tags, and alt tags to further boost your quality/relevancy score. Keyword density still plays a factor as well. Be sure to check out [Google's Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769&topic=2370419&ctx=topic) for a more comprehensive overview of your options.

Answer (score 0):

What you plan to do makes perfect sense. Certainly it will give good result.

Do keyword insertion in Ads as mentioned in other answer.

As you said, Focus your landing pages only to one product. 
In home page, you might sell dog food, fish food & cat food.

Case 01: If you send all your visitors who are searching for "cat food" to home page, it might give less result

Case 02: If you send all your visitors who are searching for "cat food" to cat_food.html, it might give better result

In cat_food.html , you can do more on page optimization what needed for SEO. It will give better results.

**Having played with Adword for around 7 years, 80% of the importance is given to bidding amount, Google wants to make more money from you regardless of your Q.S / other 100s of parameter mentioned in Adwords**

**I have achieved perfect 10/10 quality score many times, But still my avg.pos is around 4, bcoz other bid higher than what i bid**

[image: If you really want top position in Google Adword, Ignore everything just bid for higher amount, you will get the 1st position]

Note: If you really want top position in Google Adword, Ignore everything just bid for higher amount, you will get the 1st position for sure.